# Switch between divs using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show-hide div using jquery on click of radio buttons. It might be a weird question to ask but my brain is not digging more and i know that is easy task to do.

Below is HTML

```
<input type="radio" value="Active Now" class="tabActive" id="active-radio1" 
/>Participations
<input type="radio" value="Not Active Now" class="tabNotActive" 
id="active-radio2" />
Droppers

<div id="tabActive" class="tab-content">

</div>
<div id="tabNotActive" class="tab-content hide">

</div>
```

Below is JS

```
$("input:radio").off().on('click',function()){
   var value = $(this).attr("class");
   $("#"+value).show();
   // I also tried
   $("#"+value).toggleClass('hide'); /*Not right way, i know :)*/
   $("#"+value+" .tab-content").toggleClass('hide')
});
```

I am not able to switch between divs due to hide class, but nothing worked

**Note: The `hide` class is being added by framework and i can not modify it.**

So, i need a perfect way to show hide these divs.

Comment: you can use inline css like  $("#"+value).css("display","block"); to show. to hide $("#"+value).css("display","none");

Comment: cmmon.. how can i handle using one click operation.. i have to then check values of radios and i do not want to harcode it

Comment: you can check hide class using hasClass and apply the logic however there are more ways also.

Comment: other ways are without using inline css @Gags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click',function()) {
  var id = $(this).attr('class'); // this is very prone to problems

  $('.tab-content').addClass('hide')
  $('#' + id).removeClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: what are the problems @Orland

Comment: You shouldn't rely to class attribute since most of the time it will have multiple values.

Comment: class is something that i can mention

Comment: You should use something like `target` or `data-target` or `tab-id`.

Comment: fantabolous @Orland.. i used data-target and it is working awesome .... many thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
    });
 });
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/eKFrW/1299/)

Comment: please do not change my HTML.. this way i know